# How to upload to a OneDrive shared folder programmatically with least user interaction?

Tags: directory, upload, onedrive, shared

one question, if it's possible, how to upload files, to a shared OneDrive folder? I'd like to make an app, that would use the OneDrive as storage, but since OneDrive SDK requires user's login, I was wondering if it's possible to first programmatically share, or somehow with least user interaction have my app's users be able to access a folder from my own OneDrive for Business 1TB account and have them chunk upload the file there instead of uploading it to their own account?

As I said, ideally I'd like to have them upload it as a if they were using their own account, that is for the app not to be dependent on their account's possible lack of space, so that if they upload a really large file it will upload to my own shared directory from my own 1TB account which I will regularly empty...

I've tried the C# OneDrive SDK and saw it's possible to chunk upload a really large file and maybe even have that OneDrive account notify my app of some upload via webhooks so that I could maybe download the newly crated files to my account afterwards but that would be my last option *if it's even possible and not against OneDrive usage guidelines*, so is it possible to do it like I would like to please, and if so how also?

Comment: did you found anything useful?

Comment: not really yet, have you? this idea's most promising, using webapp intermediary maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203248/can-you-hard-code-an-onedrive-account-in-an-webapp-using-msal-graph-client ... if you build a solution please share...thanks.